# Wrong (old) columns when creating new tables

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm writing an simple app in Xcode.
There is a problem I can't solve:

When I want to create a new table with sqlite3 I use:
`create table if not exists %@(some values...)`

the table is created just fine, but it is not creating the correct columns.
Instead, it keeps some old columns.

Tried to drop all tables and even deleted the sqlite3 file and reinstalled it...nothing works.

Is there any solutions?

Thank you!

EDITED:

Here is my code:

It seems like all the tables created correctly, but the columns inside the last table dont reflect its content from the query "create table..." above.

When I start my app I use drop table to clear all tables...

I created the sqlite3 file and added it to the project in Xcode.
I'm checking my app on a simulator and on a real iPhone device.
Tried to delete the app from the device but the problem remains when simulating again on the device.
I deleted the sqlite3 file and create a new one, added it to Xcode, but it still uses the old table columns...

After using ALTER TABLE, the table is updated with the new column, but when dropping it and create again, the old values appears again...

have no idea how to continue :\

```
        query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"create table if not exists %@(medID integer primary key, name text, start text, days integer, timesPerDay integer, complete text)",[self.nameText.text stringByAppendingString:@"Medications"]];

        [self.dbManager executeQuery:query];
        if(self.dbManager.affectedRows != 0){
            NSLog(@"4 Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = %d", self.dbManager.affectedRows);
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Could not execute the query.");
        }

        //add vet table for pet

        query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"create table if not exists %@(vetID integer primary key, name text, start text, days integer, timesPerDay integer, complete text)",[self.nameText.text stringByAppendingString:@"Veterinary"]];

        [self.dbManager executeQuery:query];
        if(self.dbManager.affectedRows != 0){
            NSLog(@"5 Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = %d", self.dbManager.affectedRows);
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Could not execute the query.");
        }

        query = @"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'";
        NSLog(@"%@",[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query]);


        query = @"pragma table_info(biVeterinary)";
        NSLog(@"%@",[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query]);


        query = @"alter table biVeterinary add column A text;";
        [self.dbManager executeQuery:query];

        query = @"pragma table_info(biVeterinary)";
        NSLog(@"%@",[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query]);
```

and here is what I get in the console:

2014-10-25 11:03:39.998 iPet2[771:14838] 1 Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1

2014-10-25 11:03:40.000 iPet2[771:14838] 2 Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1

2014-10-25 11:03:40.002 iPet2[771:14838] 3 Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1

2014-10-25 11:03:40.003 iPet2[771:14838] 4 Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1

2014-10-25 11:03:40.004 iPet2[771:14838] 5 Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1

2014-10-25 11:03:40.005 iPet2[771:14838] (
        (
        pets
    ),
        (
        biVeterinary
    ),
        (
        biVaccinations
    ),
        (
        biMedications
    )
)

2014-10-25 11:03:40.006 iPet2[771:14838] (
        (
        0,
        vetID,
        integer,
        0,
        1
    ),
        (
        1,
        visitDate,
        text,
        0,
        0
    ),
        (
        2,
        problem,
        text,
        0,
        0
    )
)

2014-10-25 11:03:40.008 iPet2[771:14838] (
        (
        0,
        vetID,
        integer,
        0,
        1
    ),
        (
        1,
        visitDate,
        text,
        0,
        0
    ),
        (
        2,
        problem,
        text,
        0,
        0
    ),
        (
        3,
        A,
        text,
        0,
        0
    )
)

THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `create table if not exists` will create a table if it doesn't exist. If it does exist, it does nothing.

If you want to remove the table and create a new one, then your intuition is correct, that you should perform a `drop` followed by `create table`. If you do that, the altered table should have the new columns. (BTW, you can also use `table_info` to identify whether needed columns are present or not, and if not, the `alter table`.)

If you're finding that the table is not reflecting the new columns, then the problem is clearly that your update is failing for some reason. Either

- you're trying to do this on the table in the app bundle (which is read only); or
- your update is failing for some reason, but you might not be detecting/reporting it correctly; or
- you're doing something that is replacing the altered table with an old one.

Without code, details about what error you're getting, information about how you're determining that the table isn't changing, etc., it's hard for us to provide any more specific counsel.